# react-virtualized scrollToIndex not working on List

Tags: react-virtualized

When attempting to scrollToIndex the screen goes blank.

Here's a codesandbox that reproduces the problem.  Just type 100 in the input box on top and click the "scroll to row" button. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/zr2r2wp1x

It's a somewhat complicated view - it uses InfiniteLoader, WindowScroller, Autosizer, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache and List.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AutoSizer,
  CellMeasurer,
  CellMeasurerCache,
  InfiniteLoader,
  List,
  WindowScroller
} from 'react-virtualized';


const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
  fixedWidth: true,
  defaultHeight: 100
});

class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollToIndex: undefined
    }
    this.list = [];
    this.makeList = this.makeList.bind(this);
    this.makeList();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  makeList() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      this.list.push("yo");
    }
  }


  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      scrollToIndex:this.inputRow.value
    })
  }

  isRowLoaded({ index }) {
    return !!this.list[index];
  }

  loadMoreRows({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
    this.makeList();
  }

  rowRenderer({ index, isScrolling, isVisible, key, parent, style }) {
    if (isScrolling) {
      return null;
    }

    if (isVisible) {
      return (
        <CellMeasurer
          key={key}
          cache={cache}
          parent={parent}
          columnIndex={0}
          rowIndex={index}
        >
          <div style={style}>
            this is row: {index}
          </div>
        </CellMeasurer>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }


  render() {

    if (this.list.length === 0) {
      return <div>No data available.</div>;
    }

    const scrollToIndex = this.state.scrollToIndex;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="number"
            ref={(input) => { this.inputRow = input; }} />
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Scroll To Row"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          />
        </div>
        <InfiniteLoader
          isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded => this.isRowLoaded(isRowLoaded)}
          loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows => this.loadMoreRows(loadMoreRows)}
          rowCount={10000}
          threshold={1}
        >
          {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
            <WindowScroller>
              {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
                <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                  {({ width }) => {
                    console.log("scroll to index", scrollToIndex)
                    return (
                      <List
                        autoHeight
                        height={height}
                        onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                        ref={registerChild}
                        width={width}
                        rowCount={this.list.length}
                        rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
                        rowRenderer={rowRenderer => this.rowRenderer(rowRenderer)}
                        scrollTop={scrollTop}
                        deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
                        style={{ paddingLeft: '0', paddingRight: '0' }}
                        scrollToAlignment="start"
                        scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
                      />
                    )
                  }}
                </AutoSizer>
              )}
            </WindowScroller>
          )}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an [updated CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p2w7jz04kj) displaying how to accomplish your desired behavior. I had to fix numerous issues with your starter code to get the example to work properly - the short answer is you were missing passing `WindowScroller`'s render prop `onChildScroll` to the `List` component's `onScroll` prop. This setup will allow both the components to communicate with each other to effectively update the list properly.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I know I'm not supposed to use this area to thank people - but I'm doing it anyway -  this was really helpful.